# SQL table design for tags. Each user has its own tags

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables, one for storing articles, one for all tags, and one for the relation between the two:

```
[table: article]
------------------------------
id        title       content
------------------------------
1         title       content
2         title       content
3         title       content


[table: tag]
----------------
id        name
----------------
1         health
2         travel
3         sports


[table: article2tag]
------------------------
article_id        tag_id
------------------------
1                 1
1                 2
1                 3
```

The first article (article_id: 1) has all the tags attached to it (tag_id 1, tag_id 2, and tag_id 3).

I only have one user on the website for now, but I'd like to create more users and each user to have its own tags which are added by them. Do I need to add a user_id to the tags table to keep track which tag belongs to which user in that case?

```
[table: tag]
-------------------------------
id        name         user_id
-------------------------------
1         health       1
2         travel       1
3         sports       1
4         sports       2
5         business     2
```

Thank you

Comment: Insufficient information perhaps. Are the user-added tags "private"? Or visible by everybody? What does it mean for a user to be associated with a tag? What is the nature of that relationship? Can multiple users add a tag? Your current approach could be fine but it depends on a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should have a junction table which stores the relationships between users and tags, but that table should not have the tag name, only the tag ID:

```
user_tags

user_id | tag_id
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 4
2       | 5
```

The reason why the tag name should *not* appear in this junction table is that a given tag could be associated with more than one user.  In that case, repeating the tag name many times would be redundant information, and wasted storage space.  Instead, keep your current tag table as is, but remove the `user_id` column.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds great but does that mean I will have 4 tables in total? articles, tag, article2tag, and user2tag?

Comment: @ZoltanKing Yes, that's right.  However, realize that the junction tables `article2tag` and `user2tag` are fairly lean, at least from the point of view that they just maintain two ID columns.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a column `user_id` to the table `tag` is the correct thing to do, like the sample data you provided, although the column `id` is needed only as a reference if you define the combination of `name` and `user_id` as the primary key.
This means of course that the column `name` would contain duplicates, because more than 1 users may define the tag `sports` or any other. But this is fine.
So in this table:

```
[table: tag]
-------------------------------
id        name         user_id
-------------------------------
1         health       1
2         travel       1
3         sports       1
4         sports       2
5         business     2
```

`sports` is defined twice, once for each of the 2 users.
If `user_id = 1` decides to rename the tag say to `water sports` then only 1 change will be made to the table by updating the row with `user_id = 1` and `name = 'sports'`.
If a user adds or deletes a tag then all you have to do is add a new row to the table or delete a row from the table.